# How can i use socket.io to increase performance of RTC multi Connection using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, rtcmulticonnection

I am using below socket.js file and port, but it freezes computer after 4-5 user comes in video conferencing.

Socket url is,

```
https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

and Port is,

```
https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com:443/
```

should i use above socket and port, OR need to create own socket.io in web server.
i am using rtc multi Connection method for video conferencing.
how to sort-out this issue, can someone knows this issue.

Comment: Find a WebRTC tutorial and follow it. Once you've got some code, then perhaps some of the more unusual options (i.e. not usually covered in a tutorial) can be addressed. As it is, your question is far too general.

Comment: I can only suggest you use your favourite search engine to find the phrase *webrtc tutorial* - and find one that you are comfortable using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are video APIs that exist that will make this a lot easier than building it from scratch. [daily-js](https://docs.daily.co/reference) does this, for example, and then you don't have to worry about handling all the edge cases across devices and browsers yourself for WebRTC.

There are a bunch of [tutorials](https://www.daily.co/blog/building-a-custom-video-chat-app-with-react/) and a [webinar guide](https://www.daily.co/blog/tag/webinar/) on the blog too if you're looking for some direction.

Comment: daily-js is just JS to use so any JS framework (or plain HTML) will work. There's a free tier (no credit card needed) or paid tiers if you want to get into the other features like live streaming. Not open source.

Full disclosure: I'm an engineer at Daily but I genuinely think it covers your use case here. Agora and Twilio are other options too if you're looking at different video APIs. Whatever you go with, it will really simplify building out the video part of your app.

Comment: help me what should i do for this rtcmulticonnection speedup